# Strange typesetting in my tables

Tags: tables

I have a table but strange things are happening, why is that?
The mistake is at the second page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs}% 
\usepackage{array,makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{|c} | }
  \cline{3-4}
  \mc{} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Condition Phase (worst case)} & \mc{} \\
  \cline{3-4}
  \mc{} & & \makecell{Condition \\ Positive/ \\ Shaded} & 
    \makecell{Condition \\ Negative/ \\ Unshaded} & \mc{\textbf{Actual}} \\
  \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{\makecell{Testing \\ Phase \\ (best case)}} & 
    \makecell{Test \\ Positive/ \\ Shaded} & 
    \makecell{True positive \\ shaded \\ $T_p$ \\ \textit{(Correct)}} & 
    \makecell{False positive \\ shaded \\ $F_p$ \\ \textit{(Incorrect)}} &
    \makecell{Precision/Positive \\ Predictive Value \\ (PPV) \\ $\frac{T_p}{T_p + F_p} \times 100\%$} \\
  \cline{2-5}
  & 
    \makecell{Test \\ Negative/ \\ Unshaded} & 
    \makecell{False negative \\ unshaded \\ $F_n$ \\ \textit{(Incorrect)}} &
    \makecell{True negative \\ unshaded \\ $T_n$ \\ \textit{(Correct)}} &
    \makecell{Negative \\ Predictive Value \\ (NPV) \\ $\frac{T_n}{T_n + F_n} \times 100\%$} \\
  \hline
  \mc{} & & \makecell{Sensitivity/Recall \\ Rate (RR) \\ $\frac{T_p}{T_p + F_n} \times 100\%$} &
    \makecell{Specificity Rate \\ (SR) \\ $\frac{T_n}{T_n + F_p} \times 100\%$} & \mc{} \\
  \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\newpage
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=4.0] @{}}
    \toprule
    $\eta^2$   & {Interpretation} \\ % 'Counted' is placed in curly braces
    \midrule
    $\eta^2$ is $<$ .13 & Small effect     \\
    $\eta^2$ is between .13 to .26   & Medium effect    \\
    $\eta^2$ is $>$ .36    & Large effect     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second column has  `S`  type, and you have text. Add braces around the contents of each cell without numbers.

Comment: @Bernard this is the solution to my question

Comment: @Bernard - Since the column in question doesn't contain *any* numeric input, I think the advice should be not to employ the `S` column type in the first place.

Comment: I@Mico: I thought- maybe the O.P.'s code was only a fragment of the real table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tabular` environment in question contains two columns, the first of type `l` (for left-aligned text), the second of type `S[table-format=4.0]`, suitable for integers with up to 4 digits. However, the second column does not actually contain numeric input. Hence, change

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=4.0] @{}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
```

and the code will compile.

---

A full MWE (note that I've simplified and rearranged the contents of the first column somewhat):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}l<{$} l @{}}
    \toprule
    \eta^2 & Interpretation \\
    \midrule
    \eta^2<0.13      & Small effect  \\
    0.13<\eta^2<0.26 & Medium effect \\
    \eta^2> 0.36     & Large effect  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```